# Botulism questions

Tags: discussion

I have seen quite a few questions recently about the safety of using garlic and olive oil together. I know there are (viable) concerns about making your own garlic oil with peeled garlic toes and olive oil in your home, but for anything else (adding garlic powder to oil, frying garlic in oil before making pasta sauce), I feel like we should have a stickied answer that assures these users that yes, it's safe to cook with garlic! Don't worry too much! Just be careful with homemade garlic oil, maybe don't make it unless you're absolutely sure what you're doing, and that's about it.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: I will point out that search yields 400 hits/questions and answers on "botulism" and 95 on botulism and garlic.  So, users have access to quite a bit of knowledge by using the search option (which should always be a first stop when asking a question).

Answer (score 1):

You are of course welcome to write a generic Q/A that can serve as an anchor for this topic. Please be precise and back it up with reliable sources if possible.

If you want to do it as kind of “community service”, you could even make it a Community Wiki.